# how to insure nothing is asked twice in array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assignment where I have to create a quiz on the USA capitals. I have to read from an input file and store the state name and capital data into an array. Then I have to ask the user what the capital of ___ is. It randomly pulls the state names from the array.

I have the quiz completely done but am having trouble with one requirement. How do I ensure that no question is asked twice? 
For example, for each run of the program, if the user has been asked what the capital of Ohio is, it should never ask about Ohio again.

If questions about all states are asked, the program should automatically present the quiz results and terminate. How do I do this? Thank you for your help.

Everything works correctly I just need to add this one requirement to it. I have a total of three classes but I only gave you the class that sets the quiz up itself:

```
public void takeQuiz() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner check = new Scanner(System.in);

    int runThrough = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double right = 0.0;
    String next = "";
    Random rand = new Random();
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    int ques = 0;

    while (runThrough == 0 && ques < 50)
    { System.out.print("What's the capital of " + list.get(ques).getName()
            + "? (STOP to quit) ");

        if (next.equals("STOP"))
        {
            runThrough++;
        }
        else 
        {
            if (next.equals(list.get(ques).getCapital()))
            {
                System.out.println("Right!");
                right++;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("No, the answer is "
                    + list.get(ques).getCapital());
                count++;
            }
        }

        ++ques;
    }
```

Comment: You can remove the asked question from your list. And adjust the random number generated.

Comment: Alternatively, you can first generate a random permutation of numbers 0 to 49, and then use them in the generated order whenever needed.

Comment: Another way is to have a bool array with true for already asked questions., where index is the same as the index of the question. Check the bool variable,if it is true ask the question,else don't. At the end you can make the array with questions null if you won't need to generate it again in the same app run.

Comment: @FredrikLundvall I can't remove the asked question because the question is a part of the quiz

Comment: @Gassa how would I generate those random numbers? I don't think I understand

Comment: @janedoe As in the answer you accepted, for example. No numbers needed, just shuffle the question list itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the easiest way to do it. Keep in mind that because no question can be repeated, at max 50 questions can be asked.

```
Random rand = new Random();
Collections.shuffle(list);

int ques = 0;
while (runThrough == 0 && ques < 50) {
    System.out.print("What's the capital of " + list.get(ques).getName()
        + "? (STOP to quit) ");

    // Your other stuff remains as is, just update
    // list.get(ques).getCapital()
    //           ^^

    ++ques;
}
```

You also need to `import java.util.*;`.

**Explaination**: Shuffle your questions list, then ask these questions in the new order.

Comment: compiler doesn't want to accept collections.shuffle. what does that do exactly and how do i import that?

Comment: Did you `import java.util.*;`? Read [this example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_shuffle.htm) to understand the `shuffle` method.

Comment: when you put //your other stuff do you mean the if else loops? and then at the end put ++ques; ? I'm confused on where to put this

Comment: I mean keep the rest of your code as it is. Just add these lines.

Comment: I imported java.util.* but its now saying: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.util.Random

Comment: Random rand = new Random();
        Collections.shuffle(list, rand.nextInt(100000));
        int ques = 0;
        while (runThrough == 0 && ques < 50)
        { System.out.print("What's the capital of " + list.get(ques).getName()
                + "? (STOP to quit) ");
            ++ques;
            if (next.equals("STOP"))

Comment: I added it and it compiled but when i run the quiz it doesn't allow the user to enter an answer. it lists all of the questions and then the answers next to them and automatically ends.

Comment: You must have forgotten to read input  `next = check.nextLine();`.

Comment: Yes! That made it work. Thank you so much for your help!!! I really appreciate it